# Npm install throws "std" has not been declared

Tags: node.js, npm, hapi.js, nvm

I have a project using node 10, built with hapijs, and handlebars.
I am using nvm to switch between different node versions
I am currently using node v10.24.1 and npm 6.14.12

if I run npm install I am getting the error below, I have tried a couple of things like:

- npm cache clean --force
- I have deleted my node modules and package-lock.json and made sure I have node 10 and npm 6
- I have uninstalled node and npm, using "which node" command to make sure that I don't have any node folder or file somewhere and I have reinstalled node and npm I am still getting the same error.

```
npm i                  
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!

> cld@2.5.1 install /home/grace/Desktop/music-c/node_modules/cld
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/grace/Desktop/music-c/node_modules/cld/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cldutil.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cldutil_shared.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/compact_lang_det.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/compact_lang_det_hint_code.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/compact_lang_det_impl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/debug.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/fixunicodevalue.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/generated_entities.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/generated_language.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/generated_ulscript.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/getonescriptspan.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/lang_script.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/offsetmap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/scoreonescriptspan.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/tote.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/utf8statetable.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld_generated_cjk_uni_prop_80.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_cjk_compatible.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld_generated_cjk_delta_bi_32.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/generated_distinct_bi_0.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_quad0122.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_deltaocta0122.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_deltaoctachrome.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_distinctocta0122.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_distinctoctachrome.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_quadchrome_16.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld2_generated_quadchrome_2.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld_generated_score_quad_octa_0122.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld-c/deps/cld/internal/cld_generated_score_quad_octa_2.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/cld/cld-c.a
  COPY Release/cld-c.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld/src/constants.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/cld/src/cld.o
../src/cld.cc:5:12: error: ‘terminate_handler’ has not been declared in ‘std’
    5 | using std::terminate_handler;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/cld.cc:6:12: error: ‘unexpected_handler’ has not been declared in ‘std’
    6 | using std::unexpected_handler;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:60,
                 from ../src/cld.cc:8:
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/node.h:573:7: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’ to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
  573 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/node.h:607:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
  607 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/cld.cc:158:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
  158 |   NODE_MODULE(cld, init);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../../nan/nan.h:60,
                 from ../src/cld.cc:8:
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = node::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:84:25:   required from here
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/v8.h:9502:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<node::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
 9502 |                reinterpret_cast<Callback>(callback), type);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = Nan::ObjectWrap; T = v8::Object; typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback = void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)]’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:64:57:   required from here
/home/grace/.cache/node-gyp/10.24.1/include/node/v8.h:9502:16: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>::Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’} to ‘Callback’ {aka ‘void (*)(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<void>&)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
make: *** [cld.target.mk:111: Release/obj.target/cld/src/cld.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/grace/Desktop/music-c/node_modules/cld/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/grace/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:191:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-53-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/grace/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin/node" "/home/grace/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/grace/Desktop/music-c/node_modules/cld
gyp ERR! node -v v10.24.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cld@2.5.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cld@2.5.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing with force flag set `npm i --force`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it as well, same result.

Comment: If you are using nvm, can you try with a later version of node or is this version specifically needed?

Comment: All right, I am trying to use a higher version now I will let you know. 
node should be >= 10.

Comment: A higher version does not make a difference so far.

Answer (score 1):

This same issue happened to me, Just Delete the file -  package-lock.json and install node modules again by using -  npm i,

Comment: I have tried that but I am getting the same result. I remember having a couple of issues with npm this solution helped Me out Apparently, it does not work with this.

Comment: then please look into your package.json it may contain any deprecated library. simple just replace that with a new one or use an alternative to that.